# How to display the dates from a column separately?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, date, disp

I have a set of data such that column 1 shows the date (in MATLAB serial number form) and column 2 shows the rainfall, as shown like this:

```
x = [ 22029   81 
      23040   90.2
      26701   90.2
      28223  188
      36973   92
      38386   99.8
      40580  117.8];
```

So far the code I have is:

```
out = x(x(:,2) > 180,:,1); %gets all the dates with rainfall greater than 180
out2 = x(x(:,2) > 80,:,1); %gets all the dates with rainfall greater than 80
c1 = out(:,1);
c2 = out2(:,1);
rain = datestr(c1); %converts from MATLAB serial number to date
rain2 = datestr(c2); %converts from MATLAB serial number to date
X = sprintf('Heaviest rainfall will occur on %s.',rain);
X2 = sprintf('Heavy rainfall will occur on %s.',rain2);
disp(X)
disp(X2)
```

My `disp(X)` works and displays:

```
Heaviest rainfall will occur on 08-Apr-0077.
```

However my `disp(X2)` does not work and displays

```
Heavy rainfall will occur on 22002003968447-------AJFAMFFpaepaeernbrrbb-------0000000000011166770010337151.
```

How do I fix my code for `disp(X2)` so that it shows:

```
Heavy rainfall will occur on 23-Apr-0060, 29-Jan-0063, 06-Feb-0073, 08-Apr-0077, 24-Mar-0101, 04-Feb-0105, 04-Feb-0105.
```

Comment: Consider moving to using [Tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html) instead of the normal MATLAB data structures. They are much more powerful for this type of formatting/sorting/querying application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because matrices are stored in column major order in MATLAB. You can reorder your `Rain2` character array before using the `sprintf` function as follows:

```
rain2(:,end+1) = ',';     rain2(end) = '.';   %For , in between and . at the end
rain2 = rain2.';  %Reordering
X2 = sprintf('Heavy rainfall will occur on %s', rain2);
```

Result:

```
>> X2
X2 =
    'Heavy rainfall will occur on 23-Apr-0060,29-Jan-0063,06-Feb-0073,08-Apr-0077,24-Mar-0101,04-Feb-0105,07-Feb-0111.'
```